# Finding the ratio of acid and conjugate base from the absorbance equation

Tags: acid-base

[image]

I am struggling on a question about acid dissociation constants.
Below is an image showing the problem but I will reiterate it here.
HX<->H+ + X-
Using the Beer-Law equation, derive that the ratio X- : HX is as follows:
A-A{HX}/A{X-}-A
Where A{HX} is the absorbance of the fully protonated solution
A{X-} is the absorbance of the fully deprotonated solution

My own attempts have been futile, for I keep getting:
epsilon{HX}(A-A{HX})/epsilon{X-}(A-A{X})
This equation would indicate that epsilon{HX}/epsilon{X-}=-1, which isn't possible
Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Welcome to CH SE site! 

Note that using photos/screenshots of text instead of typing text itself is highly discouraged.  The image text content cannot be indexed nor searched for, nor can be reused in answers.  Specifically handwritten scripts can be difficult to decipher.  Consider  copy/pasting or rewriting of at least essential parts. 

Suitable formatting can be done according to [formatting math/chem expressions/equations](https://chemistry.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/86/how-can-i-format-math-chemistry-expressions-here).

Comment: This makes no sense to me: the total absorbance, A, is the sum of the two absorbances for the weak acid and its conjugate base, and all of the terms are greater than zero at all pHs. So the ratio of concentrations must be greater than zero, but the right hand side of your last equation has a negative denominator, so the quotient is negative. Looks like a typo or something messed up.